How I can create Suggested button in library telebot

I want create like this button. HOW?
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start", "help"])

I wrote the suggested words but they did not appear to the user like the attached image. What is the reason?
Is there something called a list in the library or something like that?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can talk to @BotFather and create a commands list for your bot.
How to:

Open @BotFather
Send /mybots
Choose your bot from the buttons
Press Edit Bot
Press Edit Commands
Now send your desired commands to be shown with its description as the format asked by @BotFather
(command1 - Description)


You can actually programmatically do this as well. Please refer to the setMyCommands method.
Hope this helps!

I found the answer by using
@bot.message_handler()
def welcome_message(message):
c1 = types.BotCommand(
command="start", description="Click to start the bot"
)  # Create a command for the user to start the bot
bot.set_my_commands([c1])  # Set the available commands
bot.set_chat_menu_button(
message.chat.id, types.MenuButtonCommands("commands")

I found the answer by using:
@bot.message_handler()
def welcome_message(message):
    c1 = types.BotCommand(
        command="start", description="Click to start the bot"
    )  # Create a command for the user to start the bot
    bot.set_my_commands([c1])  # Set the available commands
    bot.set_chat_menu_button(
        message.chat.id, types.MenuButtonCommands("commands")

